# vimperator: No mapping found

Tags: firefox, vimperator

When I execute `:map` to list current key mappings I get

```
No mapping found
```

But I expect vimperator to list at least the standard key mappings. For example 'H' key - go back in history list.

I just want to ensure that before I map a key to something I don't override standard key mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try entering

```
js mappings.get(modes.NORMAL,"
```

into the vimperator console without pressing enter. Now you can just tab through all mappings of that mode. You can also try it with

```
js mappings.get(modes.INSERT,"
```

or any other mode. Doing the same thing with

```
js modes.
```

will let you tab through all available modes.

Hope that helps.